# "could not find function H" a loaded variable from txt file in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to cluster the data set "H" loaded from file but R tells "could not find function H". My code looks like as

```
H=read.table("X3.txt")
y=read.table("Y3.txt")
#X[3,]
#length(X[3])
#y
#y[3,]
m=2;R = 2; Ec = 0.001
p=1/(m-1)
Cold=matrix(c(1.89,3.76,2.47,4.76),2,2,byrow=TRUE)
C=matrix(,2,2)
M=length(H[,1])
mu=matrix(,M,R)


repeat {
for (i in 1:M){
   for (j in 1:R){
        for (k in 1:R){
            mu(i,j)= (((H(i,)-Cold(j,))^2)/((H(i,)-Cold(k,))^2))+mu(i,j)
}

 }
}
mu=1/mu;


#centre Update
for (j in 1:R){
A=matrix(,1,2);B=matrix(,1,2);
    for (i in 1:M){
            A=H(i,)*mu(i,j)^m+A;
            B=mu(i,j)^m+B
}
C(j,)=A/B;
}
# centre update end


if (abs(Cold-C)>Ec) {Cold=C
} else {break()}
} #repeat ending loop
C
```

Can somebody help me how can i get through this, when i run the code i get following error
Error: could not find function "H"

Answer (score 2):

In #centre Update part, in for loop you are using this code:
`H(i,)`
I assume that you are trying to get the first row of this H matrix. So use `[]` like this:
`H[i,]`

`()` - for function

`[]` - for matrix/data.frame subsetting